# How to address the DigiScan safe position?

Tags: dm-script

is anybody aware of a way to change the DigiScan safe position using scripting commands?

Cheers

Comment: If this is an important feature for you, you might want to request this in Gatan's bug/feature requesting form. At least later versions of GMS might then provide this. Use the [**issue and bug reporting** button](http://www.gatan.com/resources/software).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer (up to the current version GMS 3.3 at least) is:

> ### This property is only accessible via the UI.

One can *read* the position, as it is stored in the global tags (see example below), but changing the values in the tags does not set the value in the currently used parameter set.

```
string strX = "Private:DigiScan:X Beam Park Position"
string strY = "Private:DigiScan:Y Beam Park Position"
number px,py
GetPersistentTaggroup().TagGroupGetTagAsLong(strX,px)
GetPersistentTaggroup().TagGroupGetTagAsLong(strY,py)
result("\n"+px+"/"+py)
```